# ASP.Net Model Binding Issue - DataTables.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, datatables

**Edit: the problem is that url parameters are being sent like: columns[0][name] and Asp.Net is not picking up the [name] property.  How do I make Asp.Net catch the name property?**

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10 (new version) and processing server side.  I am getting an http request formatted as below:

**Request Headers:**

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Variables encoded in the request query string:**

```
draw:16
columns[0][data]:0
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:1
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:2
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:desc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:Log
search[regex]:false
```

Model binding is successfully parsing out the first level.  I can see that there are 3 columns, 1 order, and a search, but these are always null.  How should I make my model so that I can bind properly?  I have tried a dictionary and an array to no avail.

For reference here is my model that I am trying to bind:

```
public class DataTableParameterModel
{
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public DataTablesSearch search { get; set; }
        public DataTablesColumn[] columns { get; set; }
        public DataTablesOrder[] order { get; set; }
        public int folderId { get; set; } 
}

public class DataTablesColumn
{
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public DataTablesSearch search { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, my workaround. Maybe it's not the best, but worked for me.

My model definition for the binding process is the following:

```
    public class DataTablesSentParameters
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> search { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string>[] order { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string>[] columns { get; set; }
}
```